# How do I display SUM(Quantity) while using GROUP BY command in HTML

Tags: sql, ms-access, vbscript, asp-classic

I am able to display the ItemID perfectly fine and the ItemIDs group together. When I try the SQL statement in MS Access the quantities add up perfectly fine but I can't manage to replicate this in HTML.

**This is the code**

```vb
<%
dim Con,rs, sql

set con = server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
set rs = server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

Con.Open("DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; DBQ=" &    Server.MapPath("Database/Name.accdb"))

sql = "SELECT ItemID, SUM(Quantity) FROM tblCreatedItems GROUP BY ItemID ORDER    BY tblCreatedItems.ItemID"

rs.open sql, Con
%>
<body>
<table width="467" align="center">
<th colspan="5"><strong>Items Sold</strong></th>
<tr>
<td width="119"><strong>ItemID</strong></td>
<td width="165"><strong>Quantity</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<% while not rs.eof%>
<td><%=rs("ItemID")%></td>
<td>
<% dim sql2
set sql2=con.execute("SELECT SUM(Quantity) FROM tblCreatedItems GROUP BY ItemID ORDER BY tblCreatedItems.ItemID" )

    response.Write(sql2)
%></td>
</tr>
<% rs.movenext
wend
%>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: What value is printed?

Comment: The ItemID is grouped together so say K.1 has quantity 2 and another has K.1 has quantity 3. The ItemID is printed as K.1 but no value for quanity is printed. It should print 5 in the situation I described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already grouping by the `itemid` in the first query, and don't need a second query to show the sum.

In your sql  add an alias (a name to reference the field) to the `SUM` field:

change `SUM(Quantity)` to `SUM(Quantity) as NoOfItems` (or whatever you like, as an alias)

The sql statement becomes:

```sql
SELECT ItemID, SUM(Quantity) as NoOfItems 
FROM tblCreatedItems 
GROUP BY ItemID 
ORDER BY tblCreatedItems.ItemID
```

And Then:

```
<td><%=rs("NoOfItems")%></td>
```

should show your sum field.

So, your table code becomes:

```
<table width="467" align="center">
<th colspan="5"><strong>Items Sold</strong></th>
<tr>
<td width="119"><strong>ItemID</strong></td>
<td width="165"><strong>Quantity</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<% while not rs.eof%>
<td><%=rs("ItemID")%></td>
<td><%=rs("NoOfItems")%></td>
</tr>
<% rs.movenext
wend
%>
</table>
```

Comment: @Lankymart thanks for the edit. I never seem to get the code formatting correct.

Comment: Sometimes it personal choice, but ideally I'd use `backticks` for object names, function names etc in paragraphs and use 4 space indent for code blocks. You can also use the `<!-- language: lang-[replace with lang code] -->` to specify syntax highlighting if you have multiple syntax in the same post.